# Запрос с несколькими COUNT

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

Я не специалист по БД. Мой уровень это простые запросы. 
Появилась задача выцепить некоторую статистику из старой CRM ранее использовавшейся в компании(сейчас переходим на новую и конечно экономим на профильных специалистах). Прошу вашей помощи в составлении запроса.

Есть три таблицы. БД MySQL

Таблица History - это заметки.

```
NOTE - Текст комментария (VARCHAR) 
DATECR - Дата создания комментария (DATE)
IDCREATOR - ID создателя (INTEGER)
TYPE - тип заметки  (INTEGER)
```

Таблица Users- пользователи

```
IDUSER - id юзера (INTEGER) 
NAME - ФИО юзера (VARCHAR)
```

Таблица Customers - компании

```
IDCUST - id компании 
IDUSER - id пользователя кто создал 
DATECR - дата создания
```

**Задача:** Получить статистику по списку юзеров (передается список IDUSER ) за определенную дату ( начальная и конечная даты):

```
Количество созданных компаний.
Количество созданных заметок с TYPE 1
Количество созданных заметок с TYPE 2
Количество созданных заметок с TYPE 3
```

**Вывод:** Хотелось бы получить таблицу с 5 столбцами(условные названия):

```
NAME(фио пользователя) | countCompany(кол-во созданных компаний) | countType1 | countType2 | countType3
```

Пользователь может быть с нулевой статистикой как по всем значениям так и только по некоторым, его в любом случае нужно отобразить в результатах.

С уважением, Waik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
WITH 
company_stat AS ( SELECT iduser, COUNT(idcust) company_count
                  FROM customers
                  -- WHERE iduser IN (...) AND datecr BETWEEN ...
                  GROUP BY iduser ),
comment_stat AS ( SELECT idcreator, SUM(type=1) type1, SUM(type=2) type2, SUM(type=3) type3
                  FROM history
                  -- WHERE idcreator IN (...) AND  datecr BETWEEN ...
                  GROUP BY idcreator )
SELECT users.name, company_stat.company_count, comment_stat.type1, comment_stat.type2, comment_stat.type3
FROM users
LEFT JOIN company_stat ON users.iduser = company_stat.iduser
LEFT JOIN comment_stat ON users.iduser = comment_stat.idcreator
-- WHERE users.iduser IN (...)
```

> на хостинге стоит mysql 5.6.43-84.3

```
SELECT users.name, company_stat.company_count, comment_stat.type1, comment_stat.type2, comment_stat.type3
FROM users
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT iduser, COUNT(idcust) company_count
            FROM customers
            -- WHERE iduser IN (...) AND datecr BETWEEN ...
            GROUP BY iduser ) AS company_stat ON users.iduser = company_stat.iduser
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT idcreator, SUM(type=1) type1, SUM(type=2) type2, SUM(type=3) type3
            FROM history
            -- WHERE idcreator IN (...) AND  datecr BETWEEN ...
            GROUP BY idcreator ) AS comment_stat ON users.iduser = comment_stat.idcreator
-- WHERE users.iduser IN (...)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! К сожалению на хостинге стоит mysql 5.6.43-84.3, она не знает про WITH (как оказалось). Я и сам этого не знал, по-этому не уточнил сразу.

Comment: Спасибо. Немного поправил запрос чтобы отсортировать данные за опр. период, но не понимаю как добавить выборку по опр. id пользователей. Например нужно получить статистику по пользователям с ID (1,22,33). Еще Раз большое спасибо.

Comment: *как добавить выборку по опр. id пользователей* Добавить WHERE по датам (и, возможно, по пользователям, чтобы лишнего не считать) в каждый из подзапросов. А также WHERE по пользователям - в основной запрос.

Comment: призываю вас к помощи. Большое вам спасибо, но руководство все переиграло и запрос нужно составить к Firebird. Текущий вариант моего(вашего) запроса именно под Firebird не работает. Ругается на первый SELECT внутри LEFT JOIN. "Token unknow ". p/s запрос в комментарий приложить не могу. "превышена длинна". @Akina

Comment: @Waik *запрос нужно составить к Firebird.* Вы бы хоть версию указали, что ли... А вообще, это уже тянет на новый вопрос - где вполне можно дать ссылку на этот аки предшественник.

Comment: Хорошо. Так и поступлю. Создал новый вопрос. [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1004591/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-firebird-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80-2-0](новый) @Akina