# Оптимизация запроса под Firebird сервер 2.0

Tags: mysql, firebird

Вопрос перекочевал с этого поста [stackoverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1002830/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8-count)
Нужно поправить запрос под Firebird 2.0. В MySql все работало.

Запрос(имя базы правильное customer а не customers как в предыдущем посте) :

```
SELECT users.name, comment_stat.zametka, comment_stat.otkaz, comment_stat.zvonok
FROM users
          LEFT JOIN (SELECT customer.iduser
                      FROM customer
                      WHERE customer.iduser in (72)  AND Customer.datecr BETWEEN  '23.06.2011' AND '23.06.2012'
                      GROUP BY iduser ) AS company_stat ON Users.iduser = company_stat.iduser
          LEFT JOIN ( SELECT idcreator, SUM(idhisttype=0) zametka, SUM( idhisttype=47 OR idhisttype=57) otkaz, SUM( idhisttype=45 OR idhisttype=54) zvonok
                      FROM History
                      WHERE History.idcreator in (72) AND History.datecr BETWEEN '23.06.2011' AND '23.06.2012'
                      GROUP BY idcreator ) AS comment_stat ON Users.iduser = comment_stat.idcreator
          WHERE users.iduser IN (72)
```

Запрос проверяю в IBExpert 2018.8. Результат:

```
Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 3, char 22.
SELECT.
```

С уважением, Waik.

Comment: *Нужно поправить запрос под Firebird 2.0.* На официальном сайте для этой версии даже Reference Manual отсутствует. Так что и посмотреть негде, что там можно, а что не очень... PS. WITH, насколько я помню, только в 2.1 появился...

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую обновить сервер,

Comment: Выше не выходит т.к дальше перестает работать CRM(а она у нас древняя).

Comment: Ну тады ищите, где есть документация, позволяющая посмотреть/вспомнить сей древний продукт и его заморочки.

Comment: Я тестил я по ошибке на 1.5. На 2.0 немного другая ошибка, сначала не воспринимает знак "=" в SUM. Если убрать условие в SUM то ошибка "There is no Table for join".

Comment: Да, это специфическая MySQL конструкция. Меняйте `SUM(условие)` на `SUM(CASE WHEN условие THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96382/discussion-between-waik-and-akina).